# Show that the point $[0,1,0]$ is a non-singular point of $C$

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, elliptic-curves, singularity

I am self-studying *Rational Points over Elliptic Curves* (Silverman & Tate) and am working on the following question:

> $1.17$ Let $C$ be a cubic curve in the projective plane given by the homogeneous equation
> $$Y^2Z = X^3 + aX^2Z + bXZ^2 + cZ^3$$
> Verify that the point $[0,1,0]$ at infinity is a non-singular point of $C$.

I am hoping to get some feedback on my proof, and if it is wrong, could someone point me in the right direction or give a correct proof? Here's what I have:

Let $F(X, Y, Z) = X^3 + aX^2Z + bXZ^2 + cZ^3 - Y^2Z$. Then we have that
\begin{align}
    F_X &= 3X^2 + 2aXZ + bZ^2 \\
    F_Y &= 2YZ \\
    F_ Z &= aX^2 + 2bXZ + 3cZ^2 - Y^2.
\end{align}
So at the point $[0,1,0]$, we have that
\begin{align}
    F_X (0) &= 0 \\
    F_Y (0) &= 0 \\
    F_Z (0) &= 1,
\end{align}
so the point is a non-singular point.

Is this all I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misinterprted the question. You are not being asked to hunt for singular points on the curve. You are required to show that the particular point (0:1:0) is a non-singular point, so what is required is to show that, regardless of what values are taken by the parameters $a,b,c$, all three partial derivatives cannot be 0 at (0:1:0).

Comment: Okay, I understand, I've edited my answer. How does it look?

Comment: I don't think you should edit your question to such an extend: this answer _was_ a good answer to the question you asked, and you removed the part that this answer addresses. I suggest putting your original question (at least partially) back, and then either add the new question in an "EDIT: <new question>" or ask the question as a new question on this site. Your new post does look good though :)